# How to expand XMPPFramework to support stream compression?

Tags: ios, xmpp

I am developing a IM app with XMPPFramework and server force to use stream compression in communication.But XMPPFramework do not support stream compression currently.How do I expand or modify XMPPFramework to support stream compression? I can not even login in.